# What is the limiting distribution of a random bijection from $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to itself as $n \to \infty$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution, fixed-point-theorems

Let $A_n$ be the number of fixed points of a random bijection form $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ to itself. What is the distribution of $A_n$ as $n \to \infty$? What is the expected value?

Here is my idea:

I firstly calculated pmf of $A_n$
$$P(A_n = k) = {n \choose k} \frac{1}{k!}\left(\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n-k}\right)$$

I am not sure if I derive the expression correctly. If not, what is the correct one? If yes, how to proceed and calculate the limit? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the specific part about what the expected value is: that's easy to calculate from linearity of expectation with $A_n = \sum_{i=1}^n B_{n,i}$ where $B_{n,i}$ is 1 if $i$ is a fixed point and 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The expected value is much easier to compute: linearity of expectation gives that it's $n$ times the probability that a particular point is fixed, which is $\frac{1}{n}$. So the expected number of fixed points is $1$, for all $n \ge 1$.

As for the distribution, your calculation is not correct, and for $n$ sufficiently large your "probabilities" will be greater than $1$. The probability that there are $k$ fixed points is ${n \choose k}$ times the probability that some particular subset of size $k$ is fixed (and the rest isn't fixed). This is $\frac{1}{n(n-1) \dots (n-(k-1))}$ times the probability that the rest of the permutation is a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) (your $\frac{1}{k!}$ here is incorrect), which cancels most of the binomial coefficient, and we get that overall

$$\mathbb{P}(A_n = k) = \frac{1}{k!} \left( \sum_{i=0}^{n-k} \frac{(-1)^i}{i!} \right).$$

As $n \to \infty$ the derangement probability converges rapidly to $e^{-1}$, so we get

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(A_n = k) = e^{-1} \frac{1}{k!}$$

which is the pdf of a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with $\lambda = 1$.

Comment: The question you ask in the title is much more interesting and actually it's a bit hard to say the answer concisely. The answer can be expressed in terms of a Poisson-Dirichlet process: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/07/15/cycles-of-a-random-permutation-and-irreducible-factors-of-a-random-polynomial/